# Does Windows 8 RTM Support VB6 (SP6) Runtime files? If so, which ones?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vb6, windows-8, compatibility

Basically, I'm trying to find out which of the following files come packaged with the Windows 8 RTM (that is, the final version). Just to be clear, we're not wanting to know if any of the runtime files (listed below) are or were included with any of the previous versions (Beta, CTP, RS etc) or releases of Windows 8 - we are just interested in this compatibility question as far as Windows 8 RTM (Final Version) is concerned.

In addition, if possible, we would also like to know which of the below files (if any) come shipped and registered with the Windows 8 RT (on ARM) version. As far as the ARM version is concerned, you're welcome to base your answer on the latest version of Windows 8 RT (on ARM) that is available at the date and time your answer is posted. (This will also serve to future-proof this question as additional releases or versions of Windows 8 and Windows 8 RT on ARM come out).

Here are the list of files (which are basically the VB6 SP6 runtime files):

> ```
> File name         Version         Size
>
> Asycfilt.dll      2.40.4275.1     144 KB (147,728 bytes)
>
> Comcat.dll        4.71.1460.1     21.7 KB (22,288 bytes)
>
> Msvbvm60.dll      6.0.97.82       1.32 MB (1,386,496 bytes)
>
> Oleaut32.dll      2.40.4275.1     584 KB (598,288 bytes)
>
> Olepro32.dll      5.0.4275.1      160 KB (164,112 bytes)
>
> Stdole2.tlb       2.40.4275.1     17.5 KB (17,920 bytes)
> ```

Of course, the most important file in there is `MSVBVM60.DLL`, so if you cannot provide details for all files relating to both Windows Releases, then basing the answer on as many of the files possible would also be useful.

Thank you for reading and for your anticipated assistance in putting this question/answer on record.

Comment: Just a comment because I can't find an authoritative source at the moment, but I remember reading something to the effect that the full vb6 runtime would be included with the final full version (non-RT) of Windows 8.

Comment: Found it! Posting now...

Comment: Since VB6 only generates x86 code, I don't think any of the runtime files are likely to be included with Windows RT, and presumably you couldn't run your VB6 application even if they were.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Harry Johnston correct you cannot run VB6 applications on Win RT and therefore on the ARM versions of Windows 8. The support policies quoted in the answers refer to Windows 8 desktop, although that is admittedly not explicit.

Comment: @HarryJohnston This is interesting, do you think compiling to pcode or altering the compiler options in VB6 compilation configurations section would do anything to overcome this inherent problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the official support statement:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708**

> The Visual Basic team is committed to “It Just Works” compatibility for Visual Basic 6.0 applications on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 including R2, Windows 7, and Windows 8.

Comment: I'm worried that it doesn't even mention Windows RT/ARM since it has been announced, and the rest say "Since Windows 7/8 has been announced, this is an update to inform you all that we will be including vb6sp6 runtime files in Windows 7/8" etc... but not a word about RT/ARM. Worried.

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath for vb6 support from Windows on Arm.